# addition of unit step functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dirac-delta

Recently, I received an answer key for a test and I am trying to understand this line:
$$u[n-3]-u[n-4]=δ[n-3]$$

How is this possible? I cant seem to find any resource to this. Here is the original question with solution, for reference:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTMmh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Using the following relationship
$$u[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{n} \delta [k],$$
we get
$$u[n-3]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{n-3} \delta [k] = \delta[n-3]+\sum_{k=-\infty}^{n-4} \delta [k] = \delta[n-3]+u[n-4].$$

Comment: so then should it be δ[n−3]+δ[[n−4] then?

Comment: And is this only true for discrete signals?

Comment: @user4826575 Why should it be $\delta[n-3]+\delta[n-4]$? Yes, this relationship is true for discrete time signals.